# Difference between rows as new column

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is a Table

```
   RecordID   PrinterID  Date       ColorCount   BWCount     
     1          1          2/1/2013   2000         8000
     2          2          2/1/2013   3000         4000
     3          1          3/1/2013   4000         10000
     4          2          3/1/2013   5500         7000
```

These are monthly photocopier page counts.  What I need to do is add columns that calculate the difference between the monthly counts for each copier to give me a total of pages used each month for each copier.

For Example I am trying to get the result set

```
   RecordID   PrinterID  Date       ColorCount   BWCount     ColC           ColB
   1          1          2/1/2013   2000         8000       2000           8000
   2          2          2/1/2013   3000         4000       3000           4000
   3          1          3/1/2013   4000         10000      4000-2000      10000-8000
   4          2          3/1/2013   5500         7000       5500-3000      7000-4000
```

I think this will need a LEFT SELF JOIN?? but I am struggling to find examples that are similar to what I need to do.   Can anyone assist me please?

Comment: hi, correct me if i am wrong, is it u want to achieve without any parameter passing?

Comment: i can do it if your records are few, the best way is provide parameters, this will be much more easier,

Comment: Chee - I Am happy to use parameters in a stored procedure if that is suitable

Comment: Hi @MarchKirby, i guess Roman Pekar query helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
;with CTE as (
     select
         *,
         row_number() over (partition by PrinterID order by Date) as Row_Num
     from <your table>
)
select
    C1.RecordID, C1.PrinterID,
    C1.Date, C1.ColorCount, C1.BWCount,
    C1.ColorCount - isnull(C2.ColorCount, 0) as ColC,
    C1.BWCount - isnull(C2.BWCount, 0) as ColB
from CTE as C1
    left outer join CTE as C2 on
        C2.PrinterId = C1.PrinterID and C2.Row_Num = C1.Row_Num - 1
```

see [**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17934)

Comment: hi, i am using sql server 2008, but i cant run your code, there are errors =x

Comment: here u go Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'ColC'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'ColB'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'ColC'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Invalid column name 'ColC'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'ColB'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'ColB'.

Comment: Sorry, changed tge answer